# Passing dictionary from python server to vb.net client

Tags: python, json, vb.net, dictionary, network-programming

I'm just starting out with JSON. I have a working example of passing a dictionary from a python server to a python client using JSON. I am now trying to pass a dictionary from a python server (which I know works) to a vb.net client. I have less experience of network programming in vb.net than python. Here's my client vb.net code:

```
Imports System.Text
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Module Module1

    Private ClientSocket As New TcpClient
    Private ServerStream As NetworkStream
    Private _Host As String = "raspberrypi" 
    Private _Port As Integer = 2001 
    private my_dict as new Dictionary

    Sub main()
        Dim received_data As String
        Dim inStream(100000) As Byte

        ClientSocket.Connect(_Host, _Port)
        ServerStream = ClientSocket.GetStream()
        ServerStream.Read(inStream, 0, CInt(ClientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize))
        received_data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream)

        Dim output As json_result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of json_result)(received_data)

        Console.WriteLine(output.name)
        console.WriteLine(output.extension)
        Console.ReadLine()

        ServerStream.Close()


    End Sub

    Public Class json_result
        Public Property name() As String
        Public Property extension() As Integer
    End Class

End Module
```

I don't get an error - I just don't get anything. Is anyone able to point me in the right direction? I want to end up with a dictionary object.

Comment: What is the value of received_data after Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream)

Comment: Using Console.WriteLine(received_data) I get a load of carriage returns - no text.

Comment: I can't answer my own question until tomorrow and i'll be on my hols then so here it is. I tried 

    Dim output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(received_data) 

rather than DeserializeObject(of json_result) and I now get a dictionary object that I can iterate through using. 

    For Each pair In output
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value)
    Next